# How can I solve Grafana port-forwarding error (on GKE)?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, grafana, portforwarding

To access grafana UI, I do port-forwarding with following command:
"kubectl port-forward deployment/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana 3000"

And getting following error:
Unable to listen on port 3000: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:3000: bind: address already in use unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:3000: bind: cannot assign requested address]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{3000 3000}]

Then I tried to kill the pid with the following error: "lsof -i :3000" ,  "kill -9 "
But when I run port-forwarding command still getting the same error.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If your pod/deployment running ? Have you tried with a different port locally ?

Something like kubectl port-forward deployment/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana 5000 3000  and use port 5000 locally

Comment: I tried kubectl port-forward deployment/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana 3030:3000,  and I used google shell preview and write port 3030 and access the UI. However, I am geting "origin not allowed" error and cannot add datasource. Do you think it can be because port is not 3000 anymore, because grafana should run on port 3000

Comment: Hello! I installed the google cloud cli in my local machine and port is successfully forwarded to port 3000. Also, I was able to see performance metrics without "origin not allowed" error. Just to understand better, why did it work in my local machine, but not in web host?

Comment: Try specifying namespace with -n . Worked for me